# converting HBITMAP to byte array

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi

I'm working with some scanner api which returns a HANDLE to an image in BMP format(so it is said so in documentation). I'm trying to somehow get BITMAP from this handle, but for example this code doesn't work:

```
HANDLE handle = getHandleFromScanner();
BITMAP bitmap;
int u = GetObject(handle, sizeof(BITMAP), &bitmap);
```

u is 0 here and getLastError() returns 6 which means that handle is invalid. But I cannot get any other handle except through `getHandleFromScanner()` function.

May be some transformations should be done with this handle? any ideas? What is the proper way to work with bitmap handles? Or any simple api exists? Samples I found via google didn't help me.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: If it really returned a bitmap then it should have returned a HBITMAP, not a HANDLE.  Keep looking through the API to see what you can do with this handle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks guys.

The handle appeared to be the image itself, so the following code solved the problem:

```
char* pImage = NULL;
HANDLE hImage= getHandleFromScanner();
pImage = (char *)GlobalLock(hImage);
// pImage now contains the bytes of the image
```

If someone will ever need it, the Scanner is Olivetti PR2 plus scanner.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [`GetDIBits()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144879%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)? This should work but you'll need the device context as well. You may always want to call [`GetObjectType()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144905%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) on the handle to see if it is really returning an HBITMAP.

Comment: thanks. GetObjectType() returns 0 for handle, which means it can't recognize the handle type. It seems that scanner returns some bad format image.